# Split comma separated pattern from data frame in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, strsplit

I have a dataset like that:

```
Old <- data.frame(
  X1= c(
    "AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785",
    "DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5",
    "ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077",
    "AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245"
    ))


X1
AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785
DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5
ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077
AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245
```

I want to extract ";" seperated value for AD=xxx,xx than add to a new column:
Desired output is:

```
X1                                              X2
AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785       17795,54
DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5          4753,23
ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077           30,9
AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245            244,49
```

I have tried that:

```
Old$X2<-mapply(
  function(x,  i) x[i],
  strsplit(X1, ";"),
  lapply(strsplit(X1, ";"), function(x) which(x == "AD="))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub(".*AD\\=(\\d+,\\d+);.*", "\\1", Old$X1)
```

Comment: This is worked when AD=xxx,xx is at the front. AD= can sometimes be in the middle or at the end.

Answer (score 7):

I thought this could also help you:

- We first capture the `AD=` characters and then reset the starting point of the reported match with `\\K` in a way that it tells the regex engine to drop `AD=` and start the matching pattern from then on again

```
Old$X2 <- regmatches(Old$X1, gregexpr("(AD=)\\K[0-9,.]+(?=;)", Old$X1, perl = TRUE))
Old

                                         X1       X2
1 AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785 17795,54
2    DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5  4753,23
3     ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077     30,9
4      AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245   244,49
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution to separate in 5 columns

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
Old <- data.frame(
   X1= c(
      "AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785",
      "DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5",
      "ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077",
      "AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245"
   ))
```

### Code

```
Old %>% 
   # Creating 5 columns based on the separator ";"
   separate(col = X1,sep = ";", into = paste0("v",1:5)) %>% 
   # Pivotting data
   pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
   # Separating the value column based on the separator "="
   separate(value,into = c("var","value"),sep = "=") %>% 
   select(-name) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = var,values_from = value) %>% 
   unnest()
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  AD       ARL   DEA   DER   DP   
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 17795,54 139   20    20    1785 
2 4753,23  123   5     5     4784 
3 30,9     149   25    25    3077 
4 244,49   144   7     7     245
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_match` from `stringr` -

```
Old$X2 <- stringr::str_match(Old$X1, 'AD=(\\d+,\\d+)')[, 2]
Old

#                                         X1       X2
#1 AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785 17795,54
#2    DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5  4753,23
#3     ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077     30,9
#4      AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245   244,49
```

`str_match` returns a matrix, `[, 2]` is used to extract the capture group from the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `regmatches`

```
transform(
  Old,
  X2 = unlist(regmatches(X1, gregexpr("(?<=AD=)(\\d+,)+\\d+(?=;)", X1, perl = TRUE)))
)
```

gives

```
                                         X1       X2
1 AD=17795,54;ARL=139;DEA=20;DER=20;DP=1785 17795,54
2    DP=4784;AD=4753,23;ARL=123;DEA=5;DER=5  4753,23
3     ARL=149;AD=30,9;DEA=25;DER=25;DP=3077     30,9
4      AD=244,49;ARL=144;DEA=7;DER=7;DP=245   244,49
```